# Yii translations

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, multilingual

I need to find a powerful solution to work with l18n.
Cases:

- Translations needs to be stored in database;
- It have managing page;
- I can watch where this translations are used.

I think that it could be something like Yii::t + CDbMessageSource. Maybe anybody knows ready-to-deploy extension?
Thank you.

Comment: If you need powerfull i18n I recommend gettext - it is supported by Yii too.

Comment: Gettext is cool, but "Translations needs to be stored in database"...

Answer (score 2):

the tstranslation extension will help you to translate text easily.
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation
DEMO : http://tstranslation.sundevelop.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [translate](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/translate/) module? It relies on `CDbMessageSource`, uses `Yii::t` and has some functionality to manage translations.

Comment: I'll take a look, it seems to be something like I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this easy example:

**description**: [Yii: GetText _() vs Yii::t()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911839/yii-gettext-vs-yiit/28429161#28429161)