# Yii: GetText _() vs Yii::t()

Tags: php, yii, gettext, php-gettext

When translating strings in Yii with GetText, do we have to use `Yii::t($category,'message')` or gettext's `_('message')` syntax?

And then how do we pull the strings into a PO file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put strings via POEdit app: http://poedit.net/
It allow you to scan your project files and automatically add all required strings into .po file.

If it comes to difference between Yii::t($category,'message') and _('message') - you should use Yii::t($category,'message'). GetText's  _('message') works with a quite different po/mo catalog structure.

I personally use POEdit as string scanner and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I always use Yii::t('xx','yy') in order to have more control on localization.
I can split in more file under

```
message/LANG/file.php
```

with

```
<?php
  return array(
    'xx' => 'localized',
  );
?>
```

This for Yii Framework 1.x

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this:

when i have for example:

```
Yii::app()->language = en
```

in folder `messages` have I folder `en` and on this folder I have file `lang.php`

on this folder `lang.php` I have for example:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'example1'=>'search',
        'example2'=>'news',
    );
```

then when i need call view translate:

```
<?=Yii::t('lang','example1');?>
```

and result is: `search`

---

when I change: `Yii::app()->language = de`, I must have `messages/de/lang.php` and on this foler I have:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'example1'=>'Suche',
        'example2'=>'Nachrichten',
    );
```

then when i need call view translate:

```
<?=Yii::t('lang','example1');?>
```

result is: `Suche`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Yii::t() for translations. with the inbuilt `yiic message` command you can generate all the text in to language file.

Example-

```
 Yii::t('app', 'Hello World');
 Yii::t('email', 'Welcome');
```

This will generate 2 files app.php and email.php inside your messages directory. messages/en/app.php & messages/en/email.php

please find more info about Yii translations here

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n