# How to use variable parameters in Yii::t method?

Tags: yii, internationalization

It seems Yii::t can't work with variables. I was wondering is there any solution or workaround to do something like this:

```
foreach ($dicts as $dict) {
    echo Yii::t($dict,$someRandomWord);
}
```

Comment: need more info,post full code

Comment: you can use this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911839/yii-gettext-vs-yiit/28429161#28429161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it right now. It works fine! I promise, your locales or your $category is unknown/notset. Is your message  file ok?

**Check this:** 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/243/how-to-translate-and-do-the-translations-the-easy-way/#hh1

```
 //current language is turkey, system language is english
 $category = 'app';
 $message = 'english';

 echo Yii::t($category, $message);
 //İngilizce
```

Comment: It was a trivial mistake with the capital first letter in messages' filename. I have to sleep more, thanks